# Custom Save and Unpublished button for node

Tags: 8, forms

While clicking `Save as draft` button, it will save the node but while it have to redirect to the created node it gives error `The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.` and `$entity->setPublished(FALSE);` is also not working.

```
function MYMODULE_form_node_form_alter(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {
  $form['actions']['submit_unpublish'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#weight' => '-10',
    '#value' => t('Save as draft'),
    '#submit' => array_merge($form['actions']['submit']['#submit'], 
    ['MYMODULE_draft_submit_callback']),
  );
}

function MYMODULE_draft_submit_callback(array &$form, FormStateInterface &$form_state) {
    $entity = $form_state->getFormObject()->getEntity();
    $entity->set('moderation_state', 'submitted');
    $entity->setPublished(FALSE);
    $entity->save();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't use

```
 $entity->set('moderation_state', 'submitted');
```

if you don't have *Content Moderation* core module enabled

Also make sure you declare the usage of *FormStateInterface* somewhere in your *.module* file

```
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;
```

Also look in your error logs found in *admin/reports/dblog* for other possible errors

Comment: after enabled Content Moderation core module then also its same, 
after that I commented $entity->set('moderation_state', 'submitted'); then its working :) thankyou.

Comment: I have tried it again and after enabling `Content Moderation` module `workflows` is also enabled and setting `moderation_state` works.